# Maven: Couldnt find Resource-Path after Compiling to executable Jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

today i compiled my maven projekt with help of the maven-assembly-plugin to a 
executable jar. however after doing this my jar file wasnt able to resolve the
pathes.

I added this to my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>de.main.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

This projekt is dependet to another projekt. i set the dependency in the pom.xml.
and this dependet projekt isnt able to find his resource now. the path to 
the resource was /src/main/resources/Lang. after doing maven-install this folder
was moved to /classes/Lang. my dependet projekt now isnt able to find this path.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Show us the code you use to load the resource. And show us the contents of the jar file supposed to contain the resource.

Comment: Can you show your dependencies section as well please? Maven will move your /src/main/resources/* to classes/ by default.

Comment: hi,

the dependet projekt is:

    <dependency>
 <groupId>de.myGroup.myProjekt</groupId>
 <artifactId>myNeededProjekt</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>


i think the problem is that the resource folder is stored
in my dependet projekt and not in my needed projekt.

but that should also be possible

Comment: maybe it is not really clear what i want because of my bad englisch  
i try to make it more clear:  
  
  
We have two Projekts:  
-myProject  
-myNeededProject  
  
All resources are stored in myProject and i load a resource
in myNeededProject. myProject is dependet on myNeededProject.
But myNeededProject cant find the resource after maven-install.

Comment: Show us the code you use to load the resource. And show us the contents of the jar file supposed to contain the resource.

Comment: i load the resource by creating a file with a relative path.
File file = new File("src/main/resources/Lang") an continue
working with the file in myNeededProject. It works perfectly
as long as i stay in eclipse but compinling to a jar it just 
gives an Exception because he isnt able to find src/main/resources/Lang. "And show us the contents of the jar file supposed to contain the resource" this sentence i dont understand. how can i show the contents of a jar file.

Comment: shouldnt there also be the class files of the myNeededProject under /classes? because now there are only the class-files of myProject. dont really know how the jar finds the other class-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your assemby xml, you need to use a dependencySet:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>my-assembly</id>

...

<dependencySets>
   <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   <includes>
    <include>groupId:artifactId</include>
   </includes>
   </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

See [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies).

Comment: Hi, i have no assembly.xml! i just added the lines postet above to my pom.xml

Comment: I always use descriptors instead of descriptorRefs. Maybe because it is a snapshot dependency? Try to convert to a descriptor and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Things in `src/main/resources` are going on the classpath, and should be accessed through the classloader as resources - not as files located in the file system.  Just think how you would access such a resource when delivered inside a jar-file?

If you need files to be present in the file system surrounding your various jar files, you must use another mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I suspected, is that you don't load the resources correctly. You're using File IO to access a resource that is not a file, but an entry of a jar file which is in your classpath. Think about it: once you'll give your jar to an end-user of your application, (or a developer using your library), he won't have any src/main/resources/Lang on his computer. `src/main/resources` is the location of the file in your *development* environment.

To load the contents of the Lang file which is at the root of a jar in the runtime classpath, use

```
InputStream in = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Lang");
```

or

```
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Lang");
```

Note: to see the contents of a jar file, open it with any zip tool, or use the command

```
jar -tf theFile.jar
```

Comment: But in the folder /Lang are many Resources i have to load and i have to put each of them into a File.

Comment: Then do that with every resource that you must load: `InputStream in1 = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Lang/file1.txt");InputStream in2 = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Lang/file2.txt");` ...

Comment: i need them in a file not in an intputstream

Comment: What would be the point of having them in a file? Do you want to modify their contents, or just to load their contents? What is the contents of those files, and what do you do with them?

Comment: in this directory are 9182 files which i have to work with.
i cant load all this files one by one via inputstream. i need 
to get an array of all childrens of the root folder. for this i need
somthing like: File dir = new File(path); String[] children = dir.list();

Comment: There are ways to do this, but none of them is trivial. But since they're static resources, you could generate, at build time, a properties file or even a Java class containing the list of all the paths to load.

Comment: first i thought this would work:
String rootDir = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path).getFile();File dir = new File(rootDir);String[] children = dir.list();
but it again only works in eclipse not in the compiled jar. in the compiled char the line For(child : children) its says null pointer exception

Comment: Read my answer once again. A File represents some path on the file system. Your files are not in the file system, but compressed and assembled into a jar. You can't use File IO to access entries of a jar file, because jar file entries are NOT files.